# Phonegap, plugin exec function doesn't seem to get called

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I'm starting out with PhoneGap, trying to write my first Android plugin.  I am basing it on the Echo example from the docs.  It compiles and installs, but the call to exec doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone suggest what is wrong?  The index.html, Java code and config.xml are below.  I get the alert msg for "running exec" but then nothing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>PhoneGap Test App.</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <a onclick="runPlugin()" href="javascript:void(0);">Run Plugin</a><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();

            function runPlugin() {
                alert('running exec')
                exec(function(result){ alert('ok: '+result);}, function(err){ alert('Error: '+err);}, 'Echo', 'echo', ['fred']);
                alert('exec has run')
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {

    /**
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action        The action to execute.
     * @param args          JSONArry of arguments for the plugin.
     * @param callbackId    The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
     * @return              A PluginResult object with a status and message.
     */
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        try {
            if (action.equals("echo")) {
                String echo = args.getString(0); 
                if (echo != null && echo.length() > 0) { 
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, echo);
                } else {
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
                }
            } else {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.abc" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>PhoneGapTest</name>
    <description>
        Phonegap app. to test Wifi.
    </description>
    <author email="vkuruthers@gmail.com" href="http://a.com">
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Echo" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Typo possible? `function(result){ alert('ok: '+reply);}` should be `function(result){ alert('ok: '+result);}`

Comment: Good find, and I fixed that.  But still it looks like the plugin is not getting called.  What is the correct way to debug PhoneGap apps anyway?  E.g. can I single step into exec somehow?